# How do you increase the client_max_body_size in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, drupal-7, ddev

I am getting a "413 Request Entity Too Large" error when uploading large files in my local ddev instance, specifically with restoring from a large database file using Backup and Migrate.

I'm using ddev 1.5.1, PHP 7.1, nginx 1.15.3, and Drupal 7.60. I've tried providing a custom nginx config like it says in the documentation but nothing I've tried has worked. From googling, I think the issue is that the client_max_body_size is too low but and I've attempted to double that value and nothing has worked. I copied the d7 config and added in a client_max_body_size line and restart the project, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

First, for this issue you really don't want to be using backup_migrate for a restore, especially for a 100MB upload, which is way huge. `ddev import-db` happily accepts your backup_migrate *.mysql.gz file, and is ever-so-much faster and doesn't require custom config. `ddev import-db --src=/path/to/my-backup-migrate.mysql.gz`

But to do it the way you're trying to do you have to both override nginx-site.conf AND php.

In your .ddev/nginx-site.conf in the "server" section, add `client_max_body_size 1000M;` if you want to bump it to 1GB. (See [nginx custom config in docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-nginx-configuration).

In .ddev/php/bigpost.ini (name is arbitrary, see [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-php-configuration-phpini)), you'll want:

```
post_max_size = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

Then `ddev rm` and `ddev start` and you should see the upload size improved.

Comment: I didn't realize I could import a backup_migrate file with ddev commands. That's very helpful. I'll be doing that instead of using the GUI. 

Regarding your other suggestions, I actually did change those php size constraints with a custom .ini file and I still got the error so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: You have to do *both* the nginx-site.conf and the php; then you have to `ddev rm` and `ddev start`.  I tried it out and it showed up fine in the max-size constraint on the backup-migrate page. But you'll be way better off using `ddev import-db`.

Comment: I did do both, restarted the container, tried removing and starting, etc. and still couldn't get it to work. But I'll be doing ddev import-db from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today when trying to debug some long running TUS file uploads. 
Apparently the problem is not necessarily with the ddev web container but with the nginx ddev-router container. Here the request size is also limited to 100m (client_max_body_size 100m).

You can temporarily bypass this issue in by taking following steps:
- ssh into ddev-router container
- edit /app/nginx.tmpl and set a higher client max_body_size
- restart router container

This works until you remove all ddev containers (or remove the last active ddev project).